# Let $f$ be discontinuous at every point, but has only removable discontinuities, does it exist?

Tags: functions, continuity

So, as the title might have pointed out, I'm asking if a function and be discontinuous at every point, and has only removable discontinuities.
My current suggestion for a solution is the following:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0, x\,\text{is irrational} \\ 1,x\,\text{ is rational} \end{cases}$$
If such a function $f$ is to exist,
the $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ should exists for all $a$, but at the same time it should not equal $f(a)$ for all $a$, this makes me skeptical about my choice of the function, I don't know how to check if the limit doesn't exist.

The other issue is that we can only remove all the discontinuities "at once".

Comment: Your $f$ does not satisfy $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ existing for all $a$. In fact the limit does not exist for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I see, back to drawing board then.